# Typo3: Apply new layout to existing content pages

Tags: templates, typo3

I have to apply a "facelift" to a website based on Typo3(v. 4.4.10) with TemplateVoila. Now I want to make as few changes as possible to the existing content pages and overall structure, so my initial thought was to keep the Template Data Structures and create new Template Objects mapping the existing data structure onto the new design.

This approach basically works, but I've run into various problems, since the data structures also contain layout-specific instructions which conflicts with my new design; E.g. how menus should be put together and which CSS rules should be added to the pages. This means that I can't complete apply my new layout without making changes which will effect the old layout, which I want to keep intact to that i can roll back if needed.

So, short of directly changing the exists templates, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this: That is, applying a new layout to an existing Typo3 website, without changing the content pages.

I appreciate any feedback you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can wrap my head around the problem. I think for a clean solution, you have to consider doing the following (which might involve slightly more changes than intended).

1. Create a copy of your root page as a development area within your
   installation (2nd root page)
2. If needed, copy all parts of the site structure into that root page
3. Assign a copy of your Templavoila DS/TO to this page
4. Work on the layout of that copy (XML, HTML, CSS, menu structure) and finish the facelift
5. When finished, you just switch the original root page to the new Templavoila template.

Also, in case you are using a lot of sub-structures in TV: Try resolving standard issues by distinguishing them in your css files:

```
#oldlayout .container {
   [old css rules here]
}
#newlayout .container {
   [new css rules here]
}
```

and / or:

```
#oldlayout .newelement {
   display:none;
}
#newlayout .newelement {
   display:block;
}
```

Depending on the complexity of your site, you need to switch some of your content elements by hand.

Well, you probably already considered a solution like this as you seem to be an advanced user :).

In case all this doesn't help, the only solution I see is to work on a full copy of the site tree and switch the domain's root page when finished. Of course you need to update content elements that have been changed meanwhile.

I am curious about other suggestions :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :-) Yeah I've already set up multiple copies of the system for development purposes and staging etc. I've come a bit further since yesterday and it looks as if changing the old design directly isn't going to be a problem as long as I don't remove any existing data-elements (which might cause content data to be lost).